# Can we install other applications on SQL Server VM?

Tags: sql-server

We have a SQL Server VM with a SQL Server instance running on it. Can we install other software on it including the application server on this SQL Server VM? And can we use it as a jump server to connect other SQL Server databases and managed instances?

I have a SQL Server VM with many other software installed on it and it is being used as a jump server. Want to know if we can continue with it or shall not be used for other purposes.

Want to know the cons of this approach.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is considered a bad practice.
Reasons:

- You are using resources (CPU/Memory/IO/Network) from your (expensive) SQL Server
- Your SQL Server license is paid by core, so if you would need to scale because of the other applications, this would impact your SQL server licensing cost.
- SQL Server will consume the amount of memory that is configured, so if you set it to 90% of that server, your app server won't have any memory to use.
- Troubleshooting will become harder because of shared resources.
- Security: You'll open more ports then the SQL server ports increasing the attack surface
- SQL server also has a specific set of best practices for the host. Eg: Disk Sector size, ...
- If you enable lock pages in memory together with apps running on the same server, you are going to have a bad time.

...

So host your applications on a different server preferably in a different subnet for security reasons.
Create a seperate jump box, because remote sessions will always impact performance, even if they are idle.